# Django - InheritanceManager is not working

Tags: python, django, inheritance, subclass

I have the following simple `models.py` file:

```
from django.db import models
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

class Clique(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

class Post(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    headline = models.TextField()
    clique = models.ForeignKey(Clique,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                               blank=True,
                               null=True)
    objects = InheritanceManager()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline


class VideoPost(Post):
    video = models.BooleanField(default=True)


class ImagePost(Post):
    image = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So, there is a `Clique` model which can contain multiple `Post` instances. The `Post` instances can be `ImagePost` or `VideoPost`. Therefore, `ImagePost` and `VideoPost` both inherit `Post`.

Now, let's say I want to retrieve the ImagePost subclass instances. So, I have the following view in my views.py file:

```
class PostList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.select_subclasses(ImagePost)
```

When I pass the endpoint `posts/` in the url, then this view will be triggered and it should give me only the `ImagePost` instances, right ? But I also get the `VideoPost` instances from the database:

```
[
    {
        "clique": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cliques/1/", 
        "comment_set": [], 
        "created": "2019-06-18T09:52:47.929623Z", 
        "headline": "FirstImagePost", 
        "id": 1, 
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/1/"
    }, 
    {
        "clique": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/cliques/1/", 
        "comment_set": [], 
        "created": "2019-06-18T09:53:20.266653Z", 
        "headline": "FirstVideoPost", 
        "id": 2, 
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/2/"
    }
]
```

Why is this happening ? I walked through the official doc [here](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/managers.html) . Can somebody help

Just for the sake of completeness, my `serializers.py` file looks like the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from posts.models import Post, VideoPost, ImagePost, Clique

class CliqueSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Clique
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'post_set')
        read_only_fields = ('post_set', )

class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'created', 'headline', 'clique', 'comment_set',)
        read_only_fields = ('comment_set',)


class VideoPostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VideoPost
        fields = '__all__'


class ImagePostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ImagePost
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation, it seems like `select_subclasses` does not filter by subclass type for you, it only converts it to the subclass if it matches what you supplied.

in your case

```
Post.objects.select_subclasses(ImagePost)
```

will convert all ImagePost to ImagePost instance, leaving the other ones as Post object, it doesn't filter it out.

from the doc here:

```
nearby_places = Place.objects.select_subclasses("restaurant")
# restaurants will be Restaurant instances, bars will still be Place instances
```

In your case you can simply do:

```
Post.objects.filter(imagepost__image=True).select_subclasses(ImagePost)
```

Though i don't think you need the `select_subclasses(ImagePost)` part

Comment: you could also do `Post.objects.filter(imagepost__pk__isnull=False)` this way you don't even need the boolean

Comment: @rabbit.arraron this adds extra join on each child on Post class. If user could have 15 children classes from Post, query became very heavy